# Button Background Image Check?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Pls i have a problem with trying to check the background Image of a button. I want to delete the button if its image matches an Image in the Resource Folder. I have Tried

```
    private void DeleteCard(Button btn)
    {
        if (btn.BackgroundImage.Equals( FunWaysInc.Properties.Resources.Card_1))
        {
            playersCards.Remove(Properties.Resources.Card_1);
            MessageBox.Show(playersCards.Count.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO");
        }
    }

    private void frmQuickSpark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button tstbtn = new Button();
        tstbtn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Card_1;
        DeleteCard(tstbtn);
    }
```

but the message box displayed is the one that displays "NO"..

Pls what is happening????

Comment: Are you setting the background image somewhere?  Why not also Tag the button then go off of that?  I don't really know if you can retrieve the image name

Comment: I am only setting the background image in the form_load event

Comment: Okay so can you set Tags for the buttons to be deleted there?

Comment: @Jonesy Pls how do i that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found an answer to my question.. I just modified my code

```
private void DeleteCard(Image img)
{
    playersCards.Add(Properties.Resources.Card_1);
    if (img == playersCards[0])
    {
        playersCards.Remove(Properties.Resources.Card_1);
        MessageBox.Show(playersCards.Count.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NO");
    }
}

private void frmQuickSpark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button tstbtn = new Button();
    tstbtn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Card_1;
    Image img = tstbtn.BackgroundImage;
    DeleteCard(img);
}
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here what you have to do. You need to enumerate all your images and store pointer in Tag property of the button.

```
private Dictionary<string, Image> _table = new Dictionary<string, Image>();

private void frmQuickSpark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _table.Add("Image1", Properties.Resources.Card_1);
        _table.Add("Image2", Properties.Resources.Card_2);
        Button btn = new Button();
        SetButtonImage(btn);
        DeleteCard(btn);
    }
 private void SetButtonImage(Button button)
    {

        button.BackgroundImage = _table["Image1"];
        button.BackgroundImage.Tag = "Image1";

    }

    private void DeleteCard(Button btn)
    {
         if (btn.BackgroundImage.Tag == "Image1") 
         {
             playersCards.Remove(btn); // not sure what your logic of removal
             MessageBox.Show(playersCards.Count.ToString());
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("NO");
         }
     }
```

Comment: An error occured in

        button.BackgroundImage.Tag = Properties.Resources.Card_1.Name??;

Comment: You can try something like above. I just edited it. I didn't realized images have so poor choice of properties. Again, I don't know enough about your app to tell offer a better solution

Answer (score 1):

when adding the button

```
button.Tag = "ToDelete";
```

then later

```
foreach (Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if(b.Tag == "ToDelete")
    {
        //delete
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but i dont actually want to delete the button but delete if it has the background image. I have a random defined on the background image of the button so it will not always the Card_1 background image

Comment: it should be pretty easy to modify to fit that criteria

Comment: I have tried using button.BackgroundImage.Tag but it doesn't work

Comment: @Precious1tj: looks like you should be using button.Tag, not button.BackgroundImage.Tag.

Comment: @AdamV i want to actually check the button background not actually the button bcos due to the random i implemented on the button, the button background might change